# Clear input, textarea on blur and default if field is blank

Tags: javascript, input, focus, textarea, blur

I am trying to clear two input fields with classes assigned, and one textarea with a class assigned of their default values on blur and return it to default only if the field is blank when the field is exited. If the user has included their own text I require that to stay.

This is what I have thus far:

```
$("input, textarea").focus(function() {
this.value = "";
});

$(".namefield").on("blur", function() {
$(this).val("Name");
});

$(".emailfield").on("blur", function() {
$(this).val("Email");
});

$(".messagefield").on("blur", function() {
$(this).val("Message");
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The HTML `placeholder` attribute would do all of that for you.  Is that an option?  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: I have a form built through a plugin in Wordpress that generates the HTML, so I cannot include the placeholder attribute, unfortunately. 

I set default values in the fields (Name, Email, Message) that I need removed on focus, and only reappear in the field if the user exits the field without adding a new value. But if a new value has been added to the field, I need it to stay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a quick note, the HTML `placeholder` attribute will do exactly what you describe natively.  I'd encourage that as a first choice if possible.  The implementation would simply be:

```
<input type="text" class="namefield" placeholder="Name" />
```

More reading on it is here:  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp

If you can't add attributes to the elements, but you have the value set, you can add the attributes dynamically using jQuery.  You could use the jQuery method we talked about originally, or you could just add the placeholder attribute.

Here are both examples, I've also updated the JS Fiddle with a working example.

**Using Placeholder**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input, textarea").each(function() {    
        $(this).attr('placeholder',$(this).val());
        $(this).val('');
    })
})
```

**Using data-default in conjunction with the original answer**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input, textarea").each(function() {    
        $(this).data('default',$(this).val());
    })
})
```

Original Answer:

If you still need to use jQuery, you can set and check the state and compare it against a default value.  Something like this would work:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="namefield" data-default="Name" value="Name" />
<input type="text" class="emailfield" data-default="Email" value="Email" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input, textarea").focus(function() {
    if($(this).data('default') == $(this).val()) {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });


  $("input, textarea").blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
      $(this).val($(this).data('default'));
    }
  });
})
```

You can see it working in this JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/77Lk4kep/1/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add data-default to the input tag. My form is being generated through a Wordpress plugin so I can only add a class, and value.

Here is an example of the input tag I can work with. 


`<input type="text" name="vfb-11" id="vfb-11" value="Name" class="vfb-text  vfb-medium   namefield">`

Comment: @user2109237 thats pretty simple, you can use jQuery to add the `placeholder` attribute dynamically from the `value`.  With a little work, you could probably update the php in the wordpress plugin to include the `placeholder` attribute right from the start.  I updated the answer with a new example.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Adding in `placeholder` there worked wonders, but now the fields aren't clearing on focus. I tried to pair your solution with my original solution with no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: If you use the jquery to add the `placeholder`, you'd need to remove the other jquery you tried - its adding values to the fields and is no longer needed.

Comment: Yup, I've done that and the result is that when I focus on the field the cursor is at the beginning of the default value and if I type it is replaced, however it is still visible when I first enter the field.

Comment: @user2109237 thats the default behavior for the placeholder attribute.  It keeps the placeholder text until the user types something.